# Where does truecrypt store the backup volume header?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, encryption, truecrypt

When using WDE, where does (if anywhere) truecrypt store a backup volume header? As i know there is always a backup header for regular truecrypt volumes, however i am not sure if this applies when system encryption is used.

Because if i damage the volume header in track 0, my password won't boot my system anymore. So there is no backup header on the drive?

I read somewhere on a forum that truecrypt might have a backup header relative to some position from the END of the HDD, however this doesn't make sense as it could easily be wiped over by programs running in Windows. And how would truecrypt know where this backup is anyway?

Answer (score 2):

[Volume Format Specification:](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=volume-format-specification)

> Offset: *S*-131072‡
>
> Size: 65536
>
> Status: Encrypted / Unencrypted§
>
> Description: Backup header (encrypted with a different header key derived using a different salt). **For system encryption, this item is omitted.‡‡** See bytes 0–65535.

You can create your own backups using *Tools* → *Backup volume header*.

Comment: So system encryption only has 1 volume header, at the end of track 0? There are 63 sectors per track and track 62 has the volume header, so what is in sector 63? Anything related to truecrypt?

Comment: @happygoluck sector 62 is the 63rd sector. 0 is the first.